# Should I Use GCD or NSOperationQueue in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS app written in Swift 3. in one of the modules i need to upload several files into a Web Server concurrently (files are chosen by the user from camera or gallery). i also have to display progress indicator for each file that indicates when upload is in progress and when upload is completed. the files are about 3-4MB each and the number of files is unknown (depends on the user) .

My Question:

should i use the low level GCD api or the higher NSOperation/NSOperationQueue abstraction ?
I have searched a lot but some got mixed answers (some say GCD and other say NSOperationQueue).i'v been struggling with this question a lot and i don't want to start coding only to find out in the end that i picked the wrong approach. (multi-threaded code is challenging anyhow)

Thank you very much!

Comment: I recommend NSOperationQueue for this task. Mainly because you can (and probably want to) cancle `NSOperations`. (Opinion based: always use the highest possible abstraction)

Comment: this is from RayWenderlich GDC Swift tutorial :   

"In general, it's best practice to use GCD if you are using simple fire-and-forget tasks. NSOperations offers better control, an implementation for handling maximum concurrent operations, and a more object-oriented paradigm at the cost of speed". 

does my case considered "simple fire-and-forget tasks"? I'm not sure. 
Thanx again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go for NSOperationQueue because it will give you more control over your task. NSOperationQueue will provide objects upon which you can also add dependencies if required.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperation?language=objc

Comment: thanx you very much!